# php strtotime does not work

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

I got an issue on below script, assume `$exp_date` is retrieved from db, I want to compare expiry date with today date to check whether membership's is still alive.

There is nothing to display but only `Time Expired`, what's wrong with the code?

The data retrieved from expiry column in db is set as varchar (which is built by ex-colleague).

```
$exp_date = "22/01/2014";
$todays_date = date("d/m/Y");
$today = strtotime($todays_date); 
$expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date);
echo $expiration_date.' | '.$today.'<br>';
if($expiration_date > $today){ 
    echo 'Still Active';
} else { 
    echo 'Time Expired';
}
```

Anyone can help with?

Comment: In Db you are storing expiration date as like this..??d/m/Y

Comment: i suggest u store your time & date using this format "Y-m-d H:i:s". easier to work around on later stage. just my opinion

Comment: Read more about this http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is working code

```
 <?php
 $exp_date = "22/01/2014";
  $exp_date = str_replace('/', '-', $exp_date);
  $todays_date = date("d-m-Y");
  $today = strtotime($todays_date); 
  $expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date);

  echo $expiration_date.' | '.$today.'<br>';

  if($expiration_date > $today){ 
      echo 'Still Active';
  } else { 
      echo 'Time Expired';
  }
?>
```

Actually strtotime() does not work with format 'd/m/Y'

hope it helps you.

Answer (score 6):

A note on the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) manual.

> Dates in the **`m/d/y`** or **`d-m-y`** formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) when possible.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
  $exp_date = "22/01/2014";
  $exp_date = str_replace('/', '-', $exp_date);
  $todays_date = date("d-m-Y");
  $today = strtotime($todays_date); 
  $expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date);

  echo $expiration_date.' | '.$today.'<br>';


  if($expiration_date > $today){ 
      echo 'Still Active';
  } else { 
      echo 'Time Expired';
  }
?>
```

Comment: The example above should work ,apparently strtotime does not work with d/m/Y date format just FYI,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in mysql itself like below:

```
select if(cur_date()>expire_date,'expire','active') as status from tableName
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
$todays_date=date('d/m/y');
$tempArr=explode('/', "22/01/2014");
$exp_date = date("d/m/y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $tempArr[1], $tempArr[0], $tempArr[2]));
$expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date);

echo $expiration_date.' | '.$today.'<br>';

if($expiration_date > $today){ 
    echo 'Still Active';
} else { 
    echo 'Time Expired';
}
```